# Binding Start/Stop text on Stopwatch.IsRunning - Property Changed

Tags: c#, wpf, stopwatch

I have something like this in xaml:

```
<Button Content="{Binding MyStopwatch.IsRunning,
        Converter={StaticResource BoolToStr}}"/>
```

I need to display Start, when `IsRunning` is false and Stop, when `IsRunning` is true.
I have no problem with converter or binding itself.

I have problem with refreshing `IsRunning` property.
When `IsRunning` **property change** while programm is running - it **does not change** Start/Stop text.

I know how to implement `INotifyPropertyChange` on my own properties.
But I dont know how to implement (something like) property change on `IsRunning`

Comment: You can't get change notification when you bind to a CLR property, it has to be either a dependency property or the class should implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: Wrap your Stopwatch into a class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged and change the IsRunning after calling Start/Stop.

Comment: @Islam - This is not true at all. We can bind to CLR property without implementing INPC. Only issue will be that binding won't be refreshed on GUI on any change in property.

Comment: @Rohit that what I mean! Edited the comment.

Comment: But in this case raising `PropertyChanged` on `MyStopwatch` will do since it is a part of binding itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update your bindings, you can call the `PropertyChanged` on property `MyStopwatch` whenever you start or stop a stopwatch.

```
OnPropertyChanged("MyStopwatch");
```

Comment: This is not working. I am not waiting for MyStopwatch property. But i am waitng for MyStopwatch.IsRunning...

Comment: Is your class where `MyStopwatch` resides implement `INPC` because i tired its working fine for me?

Comment: Your complete binding path is `MyStopwatch.IsRunning` so in case propertyChanged is raised on MyStopwatch also, it will refresh the bindings on UI.

Comment: The class where MyStopwatch resides implement INPC. When I replace MyStopwatch.IsRunning with my own bool property placed in same class like MyStopwatch it works fine.

Comment: You need to raise propertyChanged when you calling `MyStopwatch.Start()` or `MyStopwatch.Stop()`. Can you post the code from where you are doing this because i tried in samll app and its working for me.

Comment: Some problem with exact way of property in string. Now it works. Is this the best solution? I am looking for something like: NotifyIfThisPropertyChanged(MyStopwatch.IsRunning)...It is uncomfortable to call propertyChange when stop() or start()...

Comment: Only other way is to have your own customized Stopwatch which will raise events on start and stop to which you can hooked to as like mentioned in another answer.

Comment: Ok.Ok. Thnx for your comments and answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make `StopWatch` implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. What you can do, is create your own wrapper for it, and use that instead. For example:

```
public class StopwatchWrapper : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    Stopwatch _stopwatch;

    private bool _isRunning;
    public bool IsRunning
    {
        get { return _isRunning; }
        set
        {
            if (_isRunning != value)
            {
                _isRunning = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsRunning");
            }
        }
    }

    public StopwatchWrapper()
    {
        _stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        _isRunning = false;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        _stopwatch.Start();
        IsRunning = _stopwatch.IsRunning;
    }

    public void Stop() 
    {
        _stopwatch.Stop();
        IsRunning = _stopwatch.IsRunning;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```